# Can I list all the times I saved a file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-activity-api

My company uses Google Drive and we are still mainly using Microsoft Office documents.
Is it possible to see my activity or each time I saved a document in the Shared Drive even though it is not Google Documents I want to see the activity of?

I found this link https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity , but the code only returns Google Docs activity.  Not non-Google documents like Word and Excel.

Comment: I think the Google Drive Activity API may be what you want to look at.

Comment: I see there is an answer and that is good. But I'll point out that if you have the sophistication to write a script to measure this you have the sophistication to write a script that would artificially inflate this number by modifying the files, so as a measurement of productivity it seems kind of pointless.

Comment: That's true J G, but I'm not sure if any other alternatives would be any more secure.  It at least gives me a source of information to say I worked on A, B and E on a particular date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check if using [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) will fit your needs.

## [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)

- Lists the current file's revisions.

**Path parameters:**

***fileId*** - The ID of the file.

**Optional query parameters:**

***fields*** - The paths of the fields you want included in the response. If not specified, the response includes a default set of fields specific to this method. For development you can use the special value * to return all fields, but you'll achieve greater performance by only selecting the fields you need. For more information, see Return specific fields for a file.

***pageSize*** - The maximum number of revisions to return per page. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 200)

***pageToken*** - The token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response.

Response Body:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revisionList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "revisions": [
    revisions Resource
  ]
}
```

**[Revisions Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions#resource) Representation:**

You can obtain useful information related to the revision done to the file such as the modified time and last modifying user.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revision",
  "id": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "modifiedTime": datetime,
  "keepForever": boolean,
  "published": boolean,
  "publishedLink": string,
  "publishAuto": boolean,
  "publishedOutsideDomain": boolean,
  "lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": string,
    "photoLink": string,
    "me": boolean,
    "permissionId": string,
    "emailAddress": string
  },
  "originalFilename": string,
  "md5Checksum": string,
  "size": long,
  "exportLinks": {
    (key): string
  }
}
```

You can specify specific fields in your request under fields parameter so that only necessary information can be shown in the response body:

**Sample Fields Parameter:**

```
nextPageToken, revisions/id, revisions/modifiedTime, revisions/lastModifyingUser/displayName, revisions/lastModifyingUser/emailAddress
```

**Sample Response Body:**

```
{
 "revisions": [
  {
   "id": "1898",
   "modifiedTime": "2020-12-16T22:29:02.971Z",
   "lastModifyingUser": {
    "displayName": "User1 Test",
    "emailAddress": "user1@example.com"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ron.  Not sure why, but I am only seeing v2.  Not sure if there is some update I (or the company) will need to wait on.  At least I'll now be able to keep a 'work diary' to show what I have been working on and when.

Comment: My bad, i will delete my update post for the meantime. But you can still use v2 it will just give you a lot of info (unfiltered fields)

Answer (score 0):

Play with DriveApps file.getLastUpdated(). This is not the same as ALL the times you've updated it but it should get the last time the file was changed. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getLastUpdated()

Or do you really need a list of all the edit times not just the most recent one? In that case you could run a script once a day that records the lastUpdated for all the files you care about or all the files in a folder and record if they've changed. What is the use case?

Comment: I was hoping to show all the times that I saved files on the drive over a number of days.  Not just the last updated time.  It is a case of while working from home - if you are not seen to be working it is assumed you are not working.  I wanted to see if there was a way to 'track' my activity throughout the last week.  It may not be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Ron.  Revisions did the trick.
It took me a while to wrap my head around it, but these are the 2 functions I used.  I will try to put them together at some point when I have Drive API v3.

```
function listFilesInFolder() {
// get the id's of files in a folder
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(["Name", "File-Id"]);

    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(" ID STRING ");
    var contents = folder.getFiles();
    var counter = 0;
    var file;

    while (contents.hasNext()) {
      var file = contents.next();
      counter++;
      
      data = [
        file.getName(),
        file.getId(),
      ];
      sheet.getRange("C2").setValue = counter
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    };
};    
    
function fileactivity() {

  var revs = Drive.Revisions.list(" FileID String ");
  var savedList = [];
  for(var i=0; i<revs.items.length; i++) {
    var revision = revs.items[i];
//                                       modifiedByMeTime requires Drive API v3
    savedList.push([revision.kind, revision.modifiedDate]);
  };
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(savedList);
}
```